# Display image in a table based on value in the column using javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html

How to display an image in a table column based on the data present in the column using Html and Java.
Ex: if the value is greater than 5 it should display an image and if less than 5 must display another image.

Comment: Can you show the code you have written to do so

Comment: Please add some code. Have you attempted this?

Comment: This is not how stackoverflow works.You have to show what you have tried so far.Just to help you started with see this simple example:https://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/1ufcvsyq/

Answer (score 0):

It's just an example. Once you show us your code I could be more helpful.

```js
$('#td1 img').attr('src' function(){
return parseInt($(this).parent().prev().html()) > 5 ? 'src1' : 'src2';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td id="td1">
      <img />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```